# Block the DHCP server from broadcasting into the second ethernet interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have setup my DHCP server by following the instructions in https://wiki.debian.org/DHCP_Server.

This all works but the issue I am having is the DHCP server is being broadcast in the main company network. How would I stop the DHCP server from broadcasting in the main network?

Regards
Paul

My sysctl.conf is

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
# net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

###################################################################
# Magic system request Key
# 0=disable, 1=enable all
# Debian kernels have this set to 0 (disable the key)
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt
# for what other values do
#kernel.sysrq=1

###################################################################
# Protected links
#
# Protects against creating or following links under certain conditions
# Debian kernels have both set to 1 (restricted) 
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt
#fs.protected_hardlinks=0
#fs.protected_symlinks=0
```

My dhcp.conf is

```
option domain-name "mydebian";
# Use Google public DNS server (or use faster values that your internet provider gave you!):
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
# Set up our desired subnet:
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.254;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.100;
    option domain-name-servers home;
}
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
# Show that we want to be the only DHCP server in this network:
authoritative;
```

My isc-dhcp-server is

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
#DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="enp11s0"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

My /etc/network/interfaces is

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#auto enp6s0
#iface enp6s0 inet dhcp

# Assign a static IP for this DHCP server through eth0:
auto enp11s0
iface enp11s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
#    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I have set INTERFACESv6 to enp11s0 but still broadcasting in the main network.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Broadcast is core functionality of DHCP.

Comment: I just want one DHCP running in first ethernet interface and not broadcasting in the second ethernet interface. I have 7 embedded SBCs connected to the DHCP server and transferring heaps of images, and stored in the PC. The second ethernet interface is for the PC to access the main network.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use? Older versions supported `INTERFACES` declaration, not `INTERFACESv4` or v6. I suggest you stop the daemon and run dhcpd interactively using `/usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf enp11s0` command. It should bind to `enp11s0` interface only. Have a look at the messages after executing and check if it broadcasts to other interfaces also. Can you also attach `ip l` result?

Comment: For isc-dhcp you simply specify the interface on the commandline that it should work on.
How that is done is distro specific, I know there is askubuntu as well.
To verify if it is used you can use `ps aux | grep dhcp` to get the cmdline that was used